# How to scale given coordinates to show them properly in a window?

Tags: java, coordinates, line, draw, coordinate-systems

first of all I want to excuse my English and my Java knowledge but I still hope you can understand my problem.

For a homework I should draw given coordinates which are doubles ( eg. 11.05,35.04) in a window. I've got an ArrayList with all the coordinates. Now I know that i have to get the Max and Min values but I dont know how to scale them afterwards. They should be shown in a window of 1000x1000px.

Thanks in advance and if you need any further information please don't hesitate to ask me.

I dont know how to start this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For a coordinate calculate min and max values. After that you have a range of abs(max - min). Scale this to 1000.

To find a coordinate of a value x, you can use formula `1000 * (x-min) / (max - min)`

Comment: What do you mean with  "for a coordinate calculate min and max values"? Do you mean that i should find they max x, min x, max y and min y?  And can you please explain how you mean what you mean with range of abs. Thats new to me. Thank you. :)

Comment: Yes you need to calculate these values for x and y coordinates separately. By abs I mean absolute value of max-min otherwise you get negative range when your max is negative.